# How do GCC process macros when one reference the other

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

```
//foo.h

#define X TEST-9

#define TEST 10

//foo.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"foo.h"

int main(void)
{
  int a = X;
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

when I run :

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -Wall -Wextra
```

there is no outout,then run:

```
./foo
```

result is: 1

my queston is:

X references TEST,but TEST is defined after X,why can X expansion correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> X references TEST,but TEST is defined after X,why can X expansion correctly

Expansion happens *upon use*. When `X` *is used* at line `int a = X`, `#define TEST` is visible.

It's string replacement. `X` is expanded to the string `TEST-9` then that string is *rescanned for further replacements*, `TEST` is found, and then `TEST` is replaced by 10, resulting in the string `10-9`.